# continuity fourier functions

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Be *f*:$$(0,2\pi) \to \mathbb{R}$$ definid to $$ f(x) = ax^2+bx+c $$ on what *a*,*b* and *c* are real constants.

Determine the value (s) of the parameters *a*,*b* and *c* is that there is a extension $$2\pi - periodic $$ de *f* which is a continuous function.

I needed help finding those values ​​so I could do the Fourier series later.
Can you help me?

Comment: Any $a,b,c$ such that $f(0) = f(2\pi)$ will work. Btw, Fourier series do not require the function to be continuous.

Comment: but it can help me find those values ​​because the next line asks me to calculate the fourier coefficients using these values. Thanks for your help.